# JNI RegisterNatives does not work on class loaded by ClassLoader.loadClass()

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am embedding a JVM in an existing C++ application and need to register implementation of native Java functions with a class.

Consider this simple class with native functions:

```
class Native {
  static {
    System.out.println("Class 'Native' static initializer called.");
  }

  public native int f(int i);
}
```

Inside the JVM I am running OSGi which is the reason I need to get the classes using Java code (using the correct class loader) instead of loading them from JNI. However, to keep this example simple, I have left out OSGi.

I have these four different Java methods for getting a `jclass` value in C++:

```
class Bridge {
  public Class<?> getNativeClass1() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("org.example.Native");
  }

  public Class<?> getNativeClass2() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName("org.example.Native", false, getClass().getClassLoader());
  }

  public Class<?> getNativeClass3() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final Class<?> clazz = getClass().getClassLoader()
                                     .loadClass("org.example.Native");
    clazz.getMethods();
    return clazz;
  }

  public Class<?> getNativeClass4() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName("org.example.Native", true, getClass().getClassLoader());
  }
}
```

To register the native function implementation in C++ for `Native.f()` I call:

```
JNIEnv* env = ...
jclass clazz = ...; // Calling one of the four methods above.
JNINativeMethod nativeMethod = {
  (char*) "f",      // Method name 'f'.
  (char*)  "(I)I;", // Signature 'int --> int'.
  (void*) f         // Pointer to C++ implementation of function.
};
env->RegisterNatives(clazz, &nativeMethod, 1);
```

Depending on which method I use for getting the `Class<?>` instance, I get different results:

- `getNativeClass1()`: The static initializer is not executed in class `Native` when loading the class (but of course when creating an instance of the class) and the native implementation is *not* bound correctly. (Calling the native function in Java gives incorrect results or crashes the JVM.)
- `getNativeClass2()`: Same as above.
- `getNativeClass3()`: The static initializer is still not called in class `Native` when the class is loaded but the native implementation *is* bound correctly and I can call `f()` successfully.
- `getNativeClass3()`: The static initializer *is* called in class `Native` when the class is loaded and the native implementation *is* bound correctly.

So it seems that `ClassLoader.loadClass()` loads the class in a way so it is not properly initialized and `JNIEnv::RegisterNatives()` will not work properly. However, calling `Class.getMethods()` will somehow initalize the class (without invoking the static initializer) so that binding the native methods works.

On the other hand, `Class.forName(clazz, false, classLoader)` seems to work exactly like `Class.loadClass()` returning an uninitialized `Class` instance.

Can anybody explain the difference between

1. an uninitialized class like the one returned by `getNativeClass1()` and `getNativeClass2()`
2. a partially initialized class like the one returned by `getNativeClass3()`
3. a fully initialized class like the one returned by `getNativeClass4()`

and what is the most portable way to load a class before calling `JNIEnv::RegisterNatives()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So it seems that ClassLoader.loadClass() loads the class in a way so it is not properly initialized

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html):

`loadClass(String)`: "Invoking this method is equivalent to invoking loadClass(name, false)."

`loadClass(String,boolean)` (emphasis added): "If the class was found using the above steps, **and the resolve flag is true**, this method will then invoke the resolveClass(Class) method on the resulting Class object"

Those two methods are intended for internal use by classloaders that need to do something between loading and linking. I'm not sure why `loadClass(String)` is marked public, but it arguably shouldn't be.

> and what is the most portable way to load a class before calling

`Class.forName()`, which uses the context classloader and ensures that the class is ready for use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I originally used `loadClass()` is that this is the only way to load a class using the classloader of an OSGi bundle: `bundle.loadClass(String)`. The returned class did not work with `RegisterNatives`. Instead I now get the classLoader like this `classLoader = bundle.loadClass(className).getClassLoader()`. Then I use `Class.forName(className, true, classLoader)`. However, I am still a bit puzzled about the difference between `resolve` and `initialize` in `loadClass(name, resolve) and `Class.forName(name, initialize, classloader)`.

Comment: @mgd - For background on class-loading, here's the relevant section from the JVM spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.2

Comment: I find it surprising that OSGi imposes that requirement on you, although my experience with it is limited to demos (which was enough to realize that it's inserting a "trampoline" to all loaded classes).

Comment: One other comment: Your original examples didn't show a `loadClass().getClassLoader()` sequence. Since this is invoking an instance method on the loaded-but-not-initialized class, it should trigger initialization. Which means that the subsequent `Class.forName()` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for link to the JVM spec. I read the relevant parts with interest.

Comment: OSGi is (among other things) a modularisation framework using classloaders to isolate bundles (modules) from each other and enforce visibility contraints on a package level. From C++ I need to start a JVM and then launch an OSGi container within that JVM. In order to access a class in an OSGi bundle from C++ and make sure it can access the classes it is allowed to in other bundles, I need to use the bundle's classloader. So from the Java code outside OSGi I find a bundle and load the class using the bundle's classloader and return that class instance to C++.

Comment: I have tested `Class<?> clazz = bundle.loadClass(className);` followed by `clazz.getClassLoader()` but the class is still not linked and attempting to register native functions fails. Trying `clazz.getMethods()` seems to work. However, as you suggested it is probable more portable to use `Class.forName(name, true, classLoader)`.